# Single router file that manages all the routers in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2

I create a folder called `router`, there're lots of modules, for example, a module called `home.js`

```
  const router = require('koa-router')()
  router
  .get('/', async ( ctx )=>{})
  .get('/d', async ( ctx )=>{})
  module.exports = router
```

And in the index file `app.js`

```
  const Koa = require('koa')
  const app = new Koa()
  const router = new Router()
  const home = require('./router/home')
  router.use('/', home.routes())
  const help = require('./router/help')
  router.use('/help', help.routes())
  const ask = require('./router/ask')
  router.use('/ask', ask.routes())
  const user = require('./router/user')
  router.use('/user', user.routes())
  //more router.use
  app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods())
```

And I don't want there're so many codes in `app.js`, so I want to move all router requires to one file, such as `controller.js`, and then `app.js` only requires this file `controller.js`, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically load of all your routing files in case if you have all of the router files under the one directory. You can do that with this approach:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/src/routes').forEach((routerFile) => {
    if (routerFile.substr(-3) === '.js') {
        let route = require('./dist/routes/' + routerFile);
        router.use(route.path, route.router.routes(), route.router.allowedMethods());
    }
});
```

If your router files are under different directories and you need to specify each one explicitly you can just move your router creation logic into a separate module.